# How to prepend a Views query with another query?

Tags: views, database

Due to a configuration problem at my host, I'd like to execute the query "SET optimizer_search_depth=0;" in the same DB session as a specific Views query.  I looked into hook_views_query_alter() and hook_views_pre_execute(), but in both cases the query is only available as a Query object.

I think I need some way to modify the raw query string before it's executed, but (presumably) after it's built.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think you need to alter the query itself? You literally said you needed to set a …`session` value.

You can issue any query prior to the views query on that page load to achieve the desired affect. Eg `db_query('set mysql_max_group_concat=5;');`

If you want to so it in the views lifecycle you could use any hook_views_* api call which states it runs prior to query execution. Look at the views api docs.

Or you could likely use hook_page_build  for all its worth. Or hook_init ... whatever suits your needs.

Comment: For some reason I thought that each query was atomic in its own separate session.  This is basically exactly what I ended up doing; thanks!

Comment: In php most frameworks/CMSs define a single database connection per page request (eg, every thing the page has to do (and for drupal this is easily 50+ queries) happens with a single database connection handler).